# Error in glmer incorrect number of components

Tags: r

The initial model I run is the following:

```
play1 <- glmer(choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) + (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) || order), data=data.play0, family=binomial, control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e6)))
```

This doesn't converge, I get a warning. I rerun it like that:

```
 play1.b <- glmer(choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) + (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) || order), data=data.play0, family=binomial, start=list(fixef=fixef(mm1.play0), theta=getME(mm1.play0, "theta")), control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e6)))
```

It still doesn't converge. Standard deviation for x3, x4 and x5 is close to zero, so I drop those random effects and continue

```
play1.c <- glmer(choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) + 
(x1 + x2  + log(x6) || order), data=data.play0,
family=binomial, start=list(fixef=fixef(play0), 
 theta=getME(play0, "theta")[-c(5,7)]), 
 control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e6)))
```

Then I get the error message I described before, the

```
Error in getStart(start, lower = rho$lower, pred = rho$pp, "theta") : 
incorrect number of theta components (!=4)
```

I try different combinations for the c vector, but still I get the same message. Everything is numeric yes.

Comment: are all predictor variables numeric?  Can you give us a reproducible example?  It looks like the model is expecting a theta parameter of length 6; that does seem surprising based on `(x1 + x2  + log(x6) || order)`, but it's hard to tell without more information

Comment: I edited my post with the complete order of the code. And all variables are numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't give a reproducible example, so I made one up:

```
library("lme4")
set.seed(101)
dd <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3000),ncol=6,
            dimnames=list(NULL,paste0("x",1:6))))
dd$order <- factor(sample(1:25,size=500,replace=TRUE))
dd$x6 <- abs(dd$x6)
form <- choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) +
    (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) || order)
dd$choice <- simulate(form[-2],
                      newdata=dd,
                      newparams=list(beta=rep(1,7),
                      theta=rep(1,7)),
                      family=binomial,
                      weights=rep(1,500))[[1]]
```

Now fit some models:

```
mm.play1 <- glmer(choice ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) +
                   (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) || order),
               data=dd, family=binomial,
               control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e6),
               optimizer="nloptwrap"))
mm.play1b <- update(play1,start=list(fixef=fixef(mm.play1),
                      theta=getME(mm.play1, "theta")))
```

I tweaked your code a little bit (used the "nloptwrap" optimizer for a little bit of extra speed)

```
th <- getME(mm.play1, "theta")[c(1,2,3,7)]
mm.play1c <- update(mm.play1,
                    . ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + log(x6) +
                        (x1 + x2 + log(x6) || order),
                    start=list(fixef=fixef(mm.play1),
                    theta=th))
```

This works (no time to explain further at the moment, but basically you have to make sure the vector lengths match ...)

Comment: That makes perfect sense!Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: @BenBolker I got the same issue. My `lmer` model first didn't converge, then I did `ss <- getME(fit, c("theta", "fixef"))` and `fit <- update(fit, start = ss)`; then it became singular so I did `fit <- update(fit, .~.-(1|group))` and here appeared the error `Error in getStart(start, rho$pp) : 
  incorrect number of theta components (!=1)`. I could get it work adding `start = NULL` but is there any other options? Is there some place where this error is explained? Thank you!

Comment: The error occurs because `ss` is a vector that is now one element longer than it needs to be (because you dropped a random effect from the model). You have to figure out which element of `ss` to drop, *something* like `ss2 <- ss[names(ss) != "group.(Intercept)"]; update(fit, . ~. -(1|group), start=ss2)`. You could post a new question with a reproducible example, or post to `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` ...